# Integer division overflows

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, standards, integer-overflow

### The Problem

I have been thinking about integer (type int) overflows, and it occurs to me that division could overflow.

**Example**: On my current platform, I have

```
INT_MIN == -INT_MAX - 1
```

and thus

```
INT_MIN < -INT_MAX
```

and thus

```
INT_MIN / -1 > -INT_MAX / -1
```

and thus

```
INT_MIN / -1 > INT_MAX.
```

Hence, the division ( INT_MIN / -1 ) does overflow.

---

### The Questions

So, I have two questions:

1. What (cross-platform) C code could one write in order to prevent division overflows (for type (signed) int)?
2. What guarantees (in C or C++ standard) might help to devise the code?

---

For example, if the standard guarantees that we have either

```
INT_MIN == -INT_MAX - 1
```

or

```
INT_MIN == -INT_MAX,
```

then the following code appears to prevent overflows.

```
#include <limits.h>

/*
      Try to divide integer op1 by op2.
      Return
        0 (success) or
        1 (possibly overflow prevented).
      In case of success, write the quotient to res.
*/

int safe_int_div(int * res, int op1, int op2) {

  /*   assert(res != NULL);   */
  /*   assert(op2 != 0);      */

  if ( op1 == INT_MIN && op2 == -1 )  {
    return 1;
  }
  *res = op1 / op2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: As per convention, you want to return `-1` on error.

Comment: @Anon. You solve another division issue if you add also something such as `if (!op2) return 2` :)

Comment: it has something to do with how the computer performs division in  hardware

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What guarantees (in C or C++ standard) might help to devise the code?

C specifies signed integer representation as using 1 of 3 forms: sign and magnitude, two’s complement, or ones’ complement.  Given these forms, only division by 0 and two’s complement division of `INT_MIN/-1` may overflow.

**Update: 2023**: C23 is expected only support two’s complement.

> What (cross-platform) C code could one write in order to prevent division overflows (for type (signed) int)?

```
int safe_int_div(int * res, int op1, int op2) {
  if (op2 == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  // 2's complement detection
  #if (INT_MIN != -INT_MAX) 
    if (op1 == INT_MIN && op2 == -1)  {
      return 1;
    }
  #endif
  *res = op1 / op2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worthwhile to mention that it's possible that HW (CPU architectures,  FPGA's or some RTL) would halt in case you try to divide `INT_MIN/-1` without the above protections.

Comment: Or without proper handling of the exception by the underline kernel/firmware.

Answer (score 1):

1) Just as for any other operation in C, the application has to ensure that:

- the type used for the calculation itself is large enough, and
- the type of the variable where the result is stored is large enough.

The way to ensure this is to set size limits of each operand before the operation. What limits that are suitable depends on the algorithm and the purpose of the variables.

2) If you use stdint.h of the C standard, you get guarantees of how big the variables are, portably. You should never use `int` when writing portable code.

As for the case of writing a safe division routine, it would take 32 bit integers as parameters, then perform the calculation on 64 bit integers and return the result as a 32 bit integer.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*
      Try to divide integer op1 by op2.
      Return
        true (success) or
        false (possibly overflow prevented).
      In case of success, write the quotient to res.
      In case of failure, res remains untouched.
*/

bool safe_int_div (int32_t* res, int32_t op1, int32_t op2) {

  if(op2 == 0)
    return false;

  int64_t res64 = (int64_t)op1 / (int64_t)op2;

  if(res64 > INT32_MAX || res64 < INT32_MIN)
    return false;

  *res = (int32_t)res64_t;

  return true;
}
```

If further information of why the division failed is desired, replace the bool with an enum.