# Can integer division ever over/underflow, assuming the denominator <>0?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, division, integer-division

Can (true) integer division ever over/underflow (with the assumption that the denominator is not 0)?

Since the value is always either staying the same or getting smaller (since, in integer division, the smallest absolute non-zero denominator is 1, therefore the result can never be bigger than the numerator), I would assume not.

I'm asking more or less in the context of C/C++ standards, and I'm interested in how the various modern CPU architectures might handle integer division differently when it comes to defined/undefined behavior.

Comment: `int nonono = INT_MIN / -1;`

Comment: Hehe, good catch @JimRhodes, been a minute since I've used the term.

Comment: BTW `<>` should be `!=`

Comment: @pmg `<>` traditionally means greater than/less than; with numbers, it's just another spelling of `!=`. I used it more for theoretical purposes, not to indicate C syntax.

Comment: See also [Integer division overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394086/integer-division-overflows).

Comment: I'd say that's a duplicate :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since the value is always either staying the same or getting smaller...

That's what I used to think, too, but when we say that, we're quietly assuming the denominator is *positive*.

And since the denominator can be negative, there's one obscure but ruinous case: under 2's complement arithmetic, the mathematical result of `INT_MIN / -1` is a number that's one more than `INT_MAX`.

That is, on a 16-bit 2's complement machine, `INT_MIN` is −32768 which is perfectly representable, but −32768 ÷ −1 wants to be +32768, but `INT_MAX` is just 32767.  Similarly, in 32 bits, −2147483648 is representable but can't be divided by −1, either.

This is a peculiar quirk of 2's complement arithmetic, arising because the magnitude of `INT_MIN` is not quite the same as `INT_MAX`.  Under one's complement or sign/magnitude arithmetic, on the other hand, `INT_MIN` is exactly the negative of `INT_MAX`, so there's no "ruinous case", and as far as I know division is well defined for all inputs (well, except for zero in the denominator, of course).

Comment: hmmmm ... there's no such thing as "one more than `INT_MAX`" :)

Comment: @pmg yes, but it "wants to be" ;)

Comment: @pmg Smiley noted, but you're right.  Wording adjusted.

Comment: And this is why I still ask such seemingly simple questions. It's obvious now that you pointed it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Just to make it clear: *"..result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.105) If the quotient a/b is **representable**, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a; otherwise, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is **undefined**."* http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p6

Comment: @EugeneSh. in which case would a division be unrepresentable if truncated? That clause never made sense to me (why it would be undefined).

Comment: @Qix If the result is not fitting in the type - it is not represantable. It is not truncated, it is undefined.

Comment: Ah okay, right - that makes sense.

Comment: If a particular platform implements integral arithmetic using sign and magnitude instead of 2's complement form, this "ruinous case" would no longer apply since `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` would have the same magnitude, correct? (I am aware that the vast majority of platforms use 2's complement form, this is just a hypothetical)

Comment: Interestingly, from the same quote we can conclude that `INT_MIN % -1` is undefined too, even though it should result in `0`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That *is* interesting -- thanks for pointing that out.  (I shall have to keep that in mind next time I update my decimal-to-base-negative-one conversion function. :-) )

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I believe that's true.  Answer updated.

Comment: @pmg The wording says there is a "number that's one more than INT_MAX", which is certainly true, and that this number is the *mathematical result* (not the *C result*). That number/result isn't representable in the type `int`. Absolutely nothing wrong with the language being used here.

Comment: @Kaz You're not seeing the wording that pmg commented on.  (Check the history.)