# Why there is no __builtin_div_overflow function in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, built-in

There are `__builtin_add_overflow`, `__builtin_sub_overflow` and `__builtin_mul_overflow`, but there is no `__builtin_div_overflow` function in gcc.

It will overflow if you divide `INT_MIN` by -1.

Now I have to write some ugly ifs to check it by myself.

Comment: where is the question? Write this function yourself and you will avoid ugly `if`s in your app code

Comment: Maybe this is better to ask on the gcc mailing list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394086/integer-division-overflows has a few functions that do the overflow check

Comment: Is there a processor that has a division instruction that sets overflow? x86 raises a divide exception. Arm doesn't report overflow, nor does MIPS. The intrinsic likely doesn't exist because no processor supports it.